# How do I edit velocity in Roblox 2022?

Tags: lua, roblox

As part of the new updates, Roblox has decided to remove the Velocity component. Anyone know any work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this response is late, however I guess it's not too late to answer, since nobody has.

A roblox staff member has [confirmed](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/release-notes-for-464/1024130/4) that a solution to replacing the Velocity component is .GetVelocityByPosition(), however you probably want to use .AssemblyLinearVelocity() or .AssemblyAngularVelocity(), all of this really depends on the context you are using it.

> I also want to clarify, depreciation does not mean you can't use it anymore, it usually means that you are better off not using it, however, just go by the solution, it's better that way if you do.